# Why isn't this virtual host file working properly?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have this virtualhost file in sites-available and sites-enabled.  My domain is redirecting back here but it is going to the wrong /var/www/dir/prod.  My domain is now domain.com  I just changed it in here.  Can anyone give me any indication why this is not going to the right directory?
`<VirtualHost *:8080>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        ServerName dev.domain.com

        ServerAlias  test.domain.com`

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/slap/dev
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/sites/slap/dev>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    #ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    ErrorLog /dev/null

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /dev/null combined
```

`</VirtualHost>`

`<VirtualHost *:8080>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        ServerName domain.com

                ServerAlias  www.domain.com`

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/slap/prod
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/sites/slap/prod>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
```

```
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    #ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    ErrorLog /dev/null

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /dev/null combined
```

`</VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you restart apache?  Do the error logs say anything?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Listen statement for port 8080 in httpd.conf? If not that, could explain it (and the log won't display anything)

Answer (score 0):

Try the command :

```
httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```

(or maybe, depending on the way apache was packaged.. your use of sites-enabled suggests debian or ubuntu) :

```
APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data apache2 -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```

this will show how the vhosts are defined and overlap (which vhost falls within which namevirtualhost config). This may show you what is going wrong.